# Android Need to show like this on text view = "Apple, Samsung, 3 More"

Tags: android, xml, android-layout, textview

I have list of product String = "Apple, Samsung, Nokia , Blackberry , Windows" , I am showing this string on Text View  but  Now it visible complete string on textview but I want to show like this - "Apple, Samsung, 3 More"

Comment: one simple solution would be hold your products inside an array and then show first two elements and show length -2 products as third element of the textview

Answer (score 2):

try this

```
String s = "Apple, Samsung, Nokia , Blackberry , Windows";
String[] sArray = s.split(",");
if (sArray.length > 2){
    s = sArray[0] + "," + sArray[1] + "," + Saring.valueOf(sArray.length - 2) + " More";
}
```

Answer (score 1):

you have arraylist of string you can check a condition to check wheather the list is greater than 2  and then you can set text view in the condtion.Can you post what you have tried.

```
ArrayList<Strings> names=new ArrayList();
names.add("Apple");
names.add("Samsung");
names.add("Nokia");
names.add("Blackberry");
names.add("Windows");

  if (names.size()>2){
            textView.setText(names.get(0)+","+names.get(1)+","+(names.size()-2)+ "more);
        }else {

        }
```

Comment: if you add a code sample (or at least pseudo-code), the answer will be perfect.

Comment: I'm not the question owner. I think he didn't try anything so far.

Comment: i didn't try. I am just asking because I need to implement this for my upcoming task and i never done this before.

Answer (score 1):

You can do the same using this code

```
List<String> stringList = new ArrayList<String>();
    stringList.add("Apple");
    stringList.add("Samsung");
    stringList.add("Nokia");
    stringList.add("Lenovo");
    stringList.add("Moto");
    stringList.add("Micromax");

    if(stringList!=null && !stringList.isEmpty()){
        StringBuilder str = new StringBuilder();
        if(stringList.size()>2){
            for(int i=0;i<stringList.size();i++){
                if(i<=1){
                    str.append(stringList.get(i)+",");
                }else {
                    str.append(" and ").append(stringList.size()-2).append("more");
                }
            }
        }else {
            str.append(stringList.get(0)).append(stringList.get(1));
        }
        textview.settext(str);
    }
```